# max/min -width attributes don't applying to target column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to adjust table column width ('Author' column on the next link http://deploy.jtalks.org/jcommune/branches/1?lang=en).
I have added the min/max attributes to .author-col style:

```
#topics-table .author-col a {
font-size: 11px;
min-width: 140px;
max-width: 140px;}
```

However, target column still has 418 px width. I don't see any other overriding width styles. Could you help me to solve this issue and thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

`min-` and `max-width` aren't specified for tables. quotig [the w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.

if you want to achive a fixed width for your colums, you might want to try using [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout) on your table - but please note that this will fix all other columns to their given `width`, too.

**EDIT:**
taking a look at your example again, it seems to be much more simple in your case: you havn't given a `width` to your table cells but the `a` contained in them. change your css to this:

```
#topics-table .author-col a {
  font-size: 11px;
  /* widths are useless here, because an <a> is an inline-element */
}
#topics-table .author-col {
  /* give your .author-col a width instead */
  width: 140px;
}
```